# exist-db not reading gzip files

Tags: gzip, exist-db

I have just installed a new Exist-db and I'm willing to use it to parse XML files that are actually compressed in gzip.

It is my understanding that exist-db has the cappability to perform this kind of operations, but I keep getting the error MIME type invalid.

I've added a new MIME type in the mime-types.xml file with the following parameters:

```
<mime-type name="application/zip" type="binary">
  <description>GZIP archive</description> 
  <extensions>.gz</extensions> 
  </mime-type>
```

But I keep getting the same reading error.

Could somebody point me in the right direction? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

G.

Answer (score 2):

eXist-db can only work on XML data that has been parsed and processed (and indexed) into the eXist-db internal storage format. This means that the data needs to be decompressed before it can be queried; A GZIPped XML document stored in the database is considered to be "a binary blob' and cannot be queried.

When the GZIP file is stored in the database, you can use the compression:unzip() function ([link](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/compression&location=java%3aorg.exist.xquery.modules.compression.CompressionModule)) to uncompress the document. The document can then be stored in the database.